# Query parameter value isn't passed through retrofit interface, sometimes on API 23

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, android-networking

My retrofit interface is:

```
@GET("vocab/word/details")
Call<EnglishWord> getWord(@Query("word_id") int id);
```

Call:

```
Call<EnglishWord> call = getSingleWord.getWord(id);
Log.d("WORDID",String.valueOf(id));
```

WordId is logged in the next line, but the call is:

```
vocab/word/details?word_id=0
```

Similarly for another put request same thing happens, **word_id** is passed **0** while I can confirm that the id is passed to the call(through logs).

Weird part is this problem is random, I have only seen it in marshmallow and only a few time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you executing the call synchronously or asynchronously? You have to execute it or add a calkback

Comment: yes the call is asynchronous **call.enqueue(new Callback<EnglishWord>() {**

Everytihng works fine only except a few times when this happens. I don't know what else to debug.

Comment: Try and reduce the problem to an [mcve]. Are you sure you are not altering the value of id somewhere elsr?

Comment: Yes i am sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging a lot and not having a clue to my problem I tried disabling Instant run, and it works fine now.

Disabling the instant run solved the problem(hopefully). I have seen other posts (from Jan 2016) where the instant run was causing the problem, wonder why it's not fixed yet.